# 401k withdraw penalty free?

Tags: 401k, withdrawal

Can I withdraw 90% of my 401k funds (I'm under 59 years of age) under the new stimulus bill that was signed in December 2020? Even though the CARES act expired, according to this article https://www.jdsupra.com/legalnews/new-stimulus-deal-overview-of-major-90043/ it says:
Similar to the CRD provisions under the CARES Act, qualified disaster distributions:

> - Are not subject to the 10% early distribution excise tax under Section 72(t) of the Internal Revenue Code;
> - Will not be treated as violating any distribution restriction under the tax-qualified retirement plan or IRS;
> - May be repaid to a tax-qualified retirement plan or IRA by the participant within three years, and such repayment will be treated as
>   a tax-free rollover;
> - Will result in income spread over three years, unless elected otherwise by the participant (and unless recontributed and rolled
>   over); and
> - Will not be treated as eligible rollover contributions for purposes of mandatory income tax withholding and notice requirements.

Comment: Are you in a situation that is considered a "qualified disaster"?

Comment: Didn't trump declare all states as disaster areas??

Comment: Even if you _were_ over 59 1/2, you'd still have to pay _tax_ on the 401(k) withdrawal (unless you roll it over to an IRA). The 10% penalty is just a deterrent for withdrawing early.

Comment: **This is not a dupe** and the answer for the new law is **different than for CARES**. I don't know where that site got their definitions of 'similar' and 'extend', but 116-260 div N is stimulus while div EE (TCDTRA'20) is not -- and sec 301 specifically _excludes_ COVID. It would be more accurate to describe these sections, and CARES (116-136) sec 2202, as each _differently_ extending the earlier TCDTRA'19, 116-94 div Q sec 201/202.